# how to fix comment "there are numbers, should be constants"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Got comments on my piece of code which says, there are numbers , should be constants. 
What should I do to fix?
Below is my code snippet.

```
if (level < 0) { return 'XX'; }
if (level < 1) { return 'YY'; }
```

Comment: sounds like a linter not liking [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants) in your code.

Comment: Replace the numbers with constants?

Comment: @ASDFGerte actually, these are the comments I got while merging the PR. not a console error

Comment: I added a link to the related wikipedia article. A linter complaining is also not a console error.

Comment: @Utkarsh then your question is wildly off topic.

Comment: @EvikGhazarian code cannot return twice. `return` causes execution to leave the current function.

Comment: I might sound a little off topic & thats just because am new to this. I will try to be more clear from next time. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const level = 0;

const num1 = 0;
const num2 = 1;

if (level < num1) {
    console.log('XX');
}
if (level < num2) {
    console.log('YY');
}
```

Comment: What makes you think `level` wasn't already defined? How does this fix the problem the comment points out, given that it doesn't remove any numbers or add any constants?

Answer (score 1):

Probably it means you need to provide more meaningful names to `0` and `1` like:

```
const EMPTY_STATE = 0;
const VALID_STATE = 1;

if (level < EMPTY_STATE) { return 'XX'; }
if (level < VALID_STATE) { return 'YY'; }
```

Where the names for your constant can be anything that provides more context to the conditionals. Not a requirement but might be an "improvement" on your project or linter depending on your context.

Comment: Good advice in general, but people frequently misinterpret and misapply best practices, and the asker may have run into such a case. Just based on the name, `level` sounds like something that might actually represent a scalar value, in which case adding constants would be pointless and confusing.